# Can i use 1 ground wire to ground 2 outlets?

Tags: electrical

(Before I start, I am not worried about the NEC.) I have 2 outlets in my room. 1 of them has a ground wire that is run along the baseboard through the wall and down the side of my house to the basement connected to a copper pipe. I want to connect the other outlets ground to the same wire, Can i do that? Should i run my ground wire back to the Breaker panel and make it complete or is a copper pipe good enough?

Comment: Not a duplicate. i have provided more info.

Comment: It is a duplicate. On SE sites you use the edit button to provide more info, not create clutter by adking a nearly duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, it's a dup.  Edit the original question.  You are permitted to do that.  We'll help!    Dup questuons are not desired because they tend to clutter up the forum.

Answer (score 0):

If the water pipe is used as a grounding electrode for the electric service, AND the point to which you're attaching the ground wire is electrically continuous back to where the grounding electrode conductor attaches to the pipe, AND the grounding electrode conductor between the pipe and the service is properly sized.

Then yes, you can attach a properly sized grounding conductor to the water pipe. That grounding conductor can then be used as the grounding conductor for multiple outlets.

This is exactly what Harper said in [their answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/93357/33), on [your other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/93354/33). See NEC 250.130(C)(1).